# Google Community Connector metrics and dimensions not working

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I try to wrote a Google Community Connector and I have a problem with metrics and dimensions.
I have many configurations with with a list of available metrics and dimension.
Inside function `getSchema` I call an external API and fetch proper reportt condiguration based on selected reportId:

```
function getSchema(request) {

    const configParams  = request?.configParams || {configId: 1};

    const schemaUrl = `https://my.api.url/config/${configParams.configId}`;

    const params = {
        header: { ... },
        contentType: 'application/json',
    };

    const reportConfig = UrlFetchApp.fetch(schemaUrl, params);

    {...}

    const cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
    const fields = cc.getFields();2
    const types = cc.FieldType;

    reportConfig.dimensions.forEach((dimConfig) => {
        fields.newDimension()
            .setId(dimConfig.id)
            .setName(dimConfig.name)
            .setType(getCCDimensionType(types, dimConfig);
    });

    reportConfig.metrics.forEach((metricConfig) => {
        fields.newDimension()
            .setId(metricConfig.id)
            .setName(metricConfig.name)
            .setType(getCCMetricType(types, metricConfig);
    });

    return fields.build();
}
```

But in this case all dimensions and metrics are displayed as dimesions in LookerStudio.

[See how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5I5M.png)

I already spent many time and I have alwys the same result.

Does anyone has had this such problem and know how to solve it?

I have already read a simple tutorial:
https://bajena3.medium.com/building-a-custom-google-data-studio-connector-from-a-z-part-1-basic-setup-445a6d965d3f
And when I pass `schema` as an array like in this example everything work fine, but when the same fields are pushing to the array and then this array is returned, all given fields are displayed as a dimensions

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? If yes, what are the steps to be taken?